# Should I remove or comment the first and last line of a PuTTYgen public key?

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, ssh-keys, bitbucket.org

`puttygen.exe` has a nice simple interface for generating public and private keys pairs. Here's an example of a generated *SSH-2 RSA* public key where I filled out the comment field when saving:

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "rsa-key-20171211"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAijhKs074/PGGNhGbrgBTF6E/OrAd/pQSP68m
+fVbiho8AAl2z88F7x5VM0AOg7m5ZHVBc5PAjArXcZPVy2bh5xk488zGcnavvy1y
sFqiXGWb99Mp4xPRZ1E/qQD7gQjeRLCKUjQFAoH+jEuBpOWTrlmakeiVA8v9EmdX
6Kgi2SIA1nKAuZ+mBldPMAAisqFzUA2A2208LLc+U+FHRcnrTyNedDRLZOyfXaEt
1QeXoMA0wa3/UeLv5lTvWHVrQJtGOlwQdOrhfyrARIPY3IozcQ==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

However, I noticed from reading [OpenBSD](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT) that although the *comment* field (second line) is allowed, comments should be made with `#` at the beginning of the line. So I actually have a couple of questions:

- I plan to add a similar key through the [bitbucket interface (step 2)](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html), so do I need to remove the first and last line or, at least, add a `#` to comment them?
- The [OpenBSD key example](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8#X11-forwarding) has `ssh-rsa` at the beginning of the key's line, do I need to add these words as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PuTTYgen presents the generated public key in two formats.

1. [RFC 4716 key file format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4716):

   ```
    ---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
    Comment: "rsa-key-20171211"
    AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAijhKs074/PGGNhGbrgBTF6E/OrAd/pQSP68m
    +fVbiho8AAl2z88F7x5VM0AOg7m5ZHVBc5PAjArXcZPVy2bh5xk488zGcnavvy1y
    sFqiXGWb99Mp4xPRZ1E/qQD7gQjeRLCKUjQFAoH+jEuBpOWTrlmakeiVA8v9EmdX
    6Kgi2SIA1nKAuZ+mBldPMAAisqFzUA2A2208LLc+U+FHRcnrTyNedDRLZOyfXaEt
    1QeXoMA0wa3/UeLv5lTvWHVrQJtGOlwQdOrhfyrARIPY3IozcQ==
    ---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
   ```

   You get this format by using [*Save public key* button/command](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#puttygen-savepub).
2. OpenSSH `authorized_keys` file format:

   ```
    ssha-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAijhKs074/PGGNhGbrgBTF6E/OrAd/pQSP68m+fVbiho8AAl2z88F7x5VM0AOg7m5ZHVBc5PAjArXcZPVy2bh5xk488zGcnavvy1ysFqiXGWb99Mp4xPRZ1E/qQD7gQjeRLCKUjQFAoH+jEuBpOWTrlmakeiVA8v9EmdX6Kgi2SIA1nKAuZ+mBldPMAAisqFzUA2A2208LLc+U+FHRcnrTyNedDRLZOyfXaEt1QeXoMA0wa3/UeLv5lTvWHVrQJtGOlwQdOrhfyrARIPY3IozcQ== rsa-key-20171211
   ```

   You get this format directly in PuTTYgen main window in the upper box titled [*Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file*](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#puttygen-pastekey).

   [image]

---

Which format you need to use, depends on the application, you want to use the public key with. There's no generic answer to that. Bitbucket.org web interface uses the second format.

But in any case, there's no need for any manual modification of the key. You have both formats readily available in PuTTYgen.  Actually the second format is even more readily available, than the format you have in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested it several times and the message:

> Invalid SSH key.

Kept showing up if any kind of comment was added (lines with `#` at the beginning did not work as well).
So I needed to add up the `ssh-rsa` part on the first line and it only accepted the key in this form:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAijhKs074/PGGNhGbrgBTF6E/OrAd/pQSP68m
+fVbiho8AAl2z88F7x5VM0AOg7m5ZHVBc5PAjArXcZPVy2bh5xk488zGcnavvy1y
sFqiXGWb99Mp4xPRZ1E/qQD7gQjeRLCKUjQFAoH+jEuBpOWTrlmakeiVA8v9EmdX
ErVV28dUcQLhTmnsPxRp6dWDCwlmQGYCucstQDtlt7A4Dke7fFa74Wb8b0zOXcQ2
6Kgi2SIA1nKAuZ+mBldPMAAisqFzUA2A2208LLc+U+FHRcnrTyNedDRLZOyfXaEt
1QeXoMA0wa3/UeLv5lTvWHVrQJtGOlwQdOrhfyrARIPY3IozcQ==
```

Comment: For linux/bsd - comments are added after the key, normally an email address assoicated with the key, so `ssh-rsa AAAA....... djsmiley2k@stackexchange` would be valid.

Comment: @djsmiley2k nice to know that, thanks! But does bitbucket use that email line to know that I am the one doing the commits/pushes?

Comment: Nope, it's just for local info (i manage servers with hundreds of keys, it's good to know who they are for ;))